# Database documentation

Tags: asp.net

Can anyone suggest me the format of how to make and analyse database documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are tools to reverse engineer the schema of a database into a diagram that shows tables, relationships, field descriptions, etc.

Visio can reverse engineer SQL Server databases, for example.